# Calling the onMapClick() action from another button action

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to trigger the onMapClick() action on my map by pressing a button and sending it the required parameter.  The following is run whenever the map is touched:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        // animate camera to centre on touched position
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

        // Adding new latlng point to the array list
        markerPoints.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions object
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();

        // Sets the location for the marker to the touched point
        marker.position(point);

    }
```

I would like this button to replicate the same action as touching the screen except I am manually passing in a value:

```
    mButtonCompleteLoop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onMapClick(markerPoints.get(0));

        }
    });
```

An error is appearing saying that onMapClick() cannot be resolved.  Is there a certain way to do this? Or is it better to extract the onMapClick() code into a separate method that can then be called from both?

Comment: KvnH, come on, close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to guess about reasons without looking on whole code of your activity/fragment

Maybe you set your map listener as anonymous class.
If so, instead of:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //this 
    }
});
```

You should make your activity implements GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener and set listener like this

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
```

Then you can call OnMapClick from any place